# Meteor: Iterating over an Object inside of a Collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've run into this problem a few times, and it's slowly driving me insane. Short question: When given a collection which contains an Object as a field, how can we iterate over that object in a template.

Each entry in the collection can look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "jsWmXTvocbSMM5JAF",
    "userId" : "gcko4Eo3YtZaWa8aj",
    "gameId" : "eduzNj8kWv7TdiEuE",
    "scores" : {
        "team1" : 3,
        "team2" : 1,
        "losses" : 7
    }
}
```

We can easily access `{{userId}}` or `{{gameId}}` in the template, but of course `{{scores}}` just displayed [object Object], which we expected.

I tried using `{{#each scores}}`, which I have used with arrays before, but of course, that throws an error:

```
{{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.
```

Then I tried to be clever (rarely a good idea) and push a bunch of Objects into an array, and then return that to the template:

```
Template.scorePad.helpers({
    scoresArray: function () {
        var arr = [], scores = this.scores;
        for (var key in scores) {
            var obj = {};
            obj[key] = scores[key];
            arr.push(obj);
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why I thought that would be a good idea, because this just supplies the template with an array looking like this:

```
[{team1: 3}, {team2: 1}, {losses: 7}]
```

Which, yeah, great.. I can `#each` over it, but it just prints out `object Object` three times. As expected. But here I am, covering all the bases.

There is an open issue about this (regarding not being able to use `@key` with `#each`) at the [Meteor github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2194), but I'm really hoping someone has a simple solution.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095341/how-to-iterate-through-object-inside-collection-meteor-mongo) question is sort of close to what I'm doing, but not at all the same.

I also tried `#with`, with basically the same results.

Basically, I'm looking for an elegant "Meteor" way of doing this, if one even exists. Clearly I'm not an expert. So what do?

**EDIT** to answer the comments: To clarify, in the template the ideal solution (which doesn't work) would be use something like this in my html, and iterate over each key:value pair inside scores in the collection data:

`<div>
    {{#each scores}}
        {{this.key}}
        {{this.value}}
    {{/each}}
</div>`

and iterate over each key:value pair inside scores in the collection data.

Comment: Pretty sure meteor can just use the `.` dot operator to get at children within an object. So from an instance to the root of an object, you can do `{{myObj.childObj}}`.

Comment: my apologies..you are correct so far in your approach..can you simplify what exactly you are trying to do? I mean some codes and what you are trying to achieve..an example will be fine with your expect output

Comment: I left an edit at the bottom with more clarification of what I expect output. Hopefully that helps? @mariocatch, the object doesn't actually appear as an object in the template, it appears as a string. II don't think it would actually work in this case anyway because there are an invariable amount of teams, and the keys will actually be team names (like "bobTeam" or "silverBullet") so I can't call the keys by name in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
Template.scorePad.helpers({
scoresArray: function () {
    var arr = [], scores = this.scores;
    for (var key in scores) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.key = key;
        obj.value = scores[key];
        arr.push(obj);
    }
    return arr;
  }
}
```

And iterate it like this:

```
<div>
{{#each scores}}
    {{this.key}}
    {{this.value}}
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Well this -looks- exactly the same as what I did above, but your solution does seem to work. I'm going to take a moment to figure out why this works and what I did doesn't work...

Comment: I just created an array of objects `[{key:team1, value: 3}, {key:team2, value: 1}, {key:losses, value: 7}]` and accessing to it from template by 'key' and 'value' keys

Comment: Oh, I see! My returned array looked like `[{team1: 3}, {team2: 1}, {losses: 7}]` which means I can't access the key:values by the name "key" and "value" like you're doing. It does make sense, after all. Thank you!

Comment: **mizzao** gave the code like mine but on coffeescript at  [the Meteor github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2194#issuecomment-44752809)